# How can you set the clickable area of a WPF datagrid cell?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

In a datagrid where one column is editable and the other columns are read only.

The non editable column is bound to a nullable decimal field in a collection and is initially NULL, so no value is present in the column.

When trying to click this cell to get the datagrid into edit mode, the click target is very small and hard to click.

How can you set the click target size for such a cell?

[image: I would like the clickable area to be the entire cell, highlighted as shown]

Answer (score 1):

In the datagrid, use Selection Unit="FullRow". Define a default DataGridCell Style and base all other DataGridCell styles on this. Then add a row style to the DataGrid. This gives you a way to select the whole row, and have another color for the Focused cell. And the entire cell background is in the color specified in the style.

```
   <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="DgcDefault">
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush"  Value="Transparent"/>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
   <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF83B2DD"/>
       </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<DataGrid.RowStyle>
   <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
         <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue"/>
         </Trigger>
         <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
         </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are defining your own columns in the DataGrid, you could set the MinWidth property on the column so that there's always space to click on, even if the value is empty or very short. For example:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn
            MinWidth="100" 
            Header="Phone"
            Binding="{Binding Path=PhoneNumber}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I am defining my own columns, but setting the minimum width does nothing to increase the area of a cell that is clickable

Comment: Which version of the DataGrid are you using? When I tested with the DataGrid that comes with WPF 4, I can click on anywhere in the cell (indicated by the yellow highlighting in your screenshot) and I can get into edit mode.

Comment: Well, I have VS2010 SP1 so, I guess it is the latest version. Perhaps there is some sort of property that defines varying behaviour. I can only click the area of a cell that contains data